# How to extract binary data from Response data in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to extract [this data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjAgb.png) in hex form.

I have tried with `Regular Expression Extractor` and `Save Responses` to a file but these two methods extract only the plaintext which is a string of non printable characters.

The context is to simulate a VNC authentication using DES.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binary data in which form? You can add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request and use the following code:

```
def data = prev.getResponseData()
```

As a result you will have a byte array holding the response data.

I have no idea about the format, you can find the specification in the [RFC 6143](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6143)

You might need a 3rd-party library like [Vernacular VNC](https://github.com/shinyhut/vernacular-vnc) or [LGPL VNCj](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vncjlgpl/) in order to properly parse the response and get "interesting" values from there.

See [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) article to learn more about the concept

Comment: Tanks but the data extracted will be in plaintext form and I want the data in hex form (like in the picture). I have tried to do the conversion plaintext->hex but there is some non printable characters and the result is not good.